# Javascript shortand for using await in a callback

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

It makes sense that you cannot use await inside of an synchronous function. Consider the following snippet

```js
fetch('.../userdata.json')
.then(async res => {
    const data = await res.json();
    setData(state => state.data = data)
    // setData requires a sync callback in order to work
});
```

I have to define `data` so that I'm not using `await` in the callback, which feels a little redundant. Is there shorthand that would allow me to await in the callback?

Comment: `...` is what exactly? Also, why do you use `async res`? `.then` is already a callback

Comment: a url which isn't relevant to the question

Comment: i wouldn't be able to `await res.json()` if the `.then` callback function wasn't `async`

Comment: Your question is not clear at all. If you remove `async` and `await` what do you get inside the `.then(res => { console.log(res); return res.json(); }).then(data => { /*use data here!*/ })`  that you cannot make use of?

Comment: The normal way without `async` is `.then(res => res.json()).then(data => setData(state => state.data = data))`

Comment: You can very well do a `await fetch('.../userdata.json')`, and then in the next statement, `const data = await res.json();`, given wherever the `fetch` is... is an `async` method.

Comment: You might want to first take out the JSON Object using `.then(res => res.json()).then(data => { console.log(data); })`  - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch See the first example? Sometimes reviewing the Docs helps.

Comment: totally forgot about .then() chaining haha.

Answer (score 1):

Either use async/await or use callbacks.  I don't know what "shorthand" you're looking for, but you can use `await` overall if the enclosing function is `async`.  For example:

```
const someFunc = async () => {
  const res = await fetch('.../userdata.json');
  const data = await res.json();
  setData(state => state.data = data);
};
someFunc();
```

Alternatively, if you're not in an `async` function, you can't use `await`.  So this operation would involve callbacks passed to `.then()` on Promises:

```
fetch('.../userdata.json')
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => {
    setData(state => state.data = data);
  });
```

Comment: Literally shown in the first example here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Comment: setdata is not react state, which is why there is no react tag.